# No proxy provider found for type only in dev mode, classic run is corect

Tags: java, gwt, errai

I'm writing an application in Erra and I got into trouble. RPC calls using the application. When I start in normal mode, Vee running well, but when it will bring the best in dev mode throws Well proxy provider for the type found.

And there is bug screen:
[BUG FOUNDED IN WEB CONSOLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qn4eu.png)

I append some screen and source code...

### **pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.jboss.errai.demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>errai-tutorial</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>elBooker-CRM</name>

  <properties>
    <errai.version>4.0.0.Beta1</errai.version>
    <gwt.version>2.8.0-beta1</gwt.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.5.11</slf4j.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <javaee.version>1.0.2.Final</javaee.version>
    <errai.dev.context>${project.artifactId}</errai.dev.context>
    <as.version>8.1.0.Final</as.version>
    <!-- Add the absolute path for $JBOSS_HOME below to manage another instance -->
    <errai.jboss.home>${project.build.directory}/wildfly-${as.version}</errai.jboss.home>
  </properties>

  <!-- These must be here in this order because of missing guava-gwt snapshots in the JBoss Public Repository. -->
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>jboss</id>
      <name>JBoss Public Repo</name>
      <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>sonatype-public</id>
      <name>Sonatype Public Snapshots Repo</name>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/public</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
        <artifactId>erra-bus</artifactId>
        <version>${errai.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
        <artifactId>erra-ioc-bus-support</artifactId>
        <version>${errai.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.errai.bom</groupId>
        <artifactId>errai-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${errai.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava-gwt</artifactId>
        <version>20.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>20.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
      <artifactId>errai-navigation</artifactId>
      <version>${errai.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
      <artifactId>errai-javaee-all</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
      <artifactId>errai-cordova</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
      <version>${javaee.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
      <artifactId>errai-cdi-jboss</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
      <artifactId>errai-cdi-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <outputDirectory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
          <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
              <pluginExecutions>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[2.4.0,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <skip />
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[2.1,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <ignore></ignore>
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
              </pluginExecutions>
            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <logLevel>INFO</logLevel>
          <noServer>false</noServer>
          <!-- Configuration for Errai's JBossLauncher. This launcher controls a Wildfly instance in a separate JVM.
          It's configuration is more complex but useful if you encounter classloading issues using the embedded launcher. -->
          <!--extraJvmArgs>-Xmx2048m -XX:CompileThreshold=7000 -Derrai.jboss.home=${errai.jboss.home} -Derrai.dev.context=${errai.dev.context} -Derrai.jboss.javaopts="-Derrai.jboss.javaagent.path=${settings.localRepository}/org/jboss/errai/errai-client-local-class-hider/${errai.version}/errai-client-local-class-hider-${errai.version}.jar</extraJvmArgs>
          <server>org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.gwt.JBossLauncher</server-->

          <!-- Errai's embedded WildFly launcher can be used to simplify IDE run configs as
          server-side code can then be debugged directly (without needing to set up a
          remote debugger) -->
          <!-- Errai will automatically skip deployment for classes under /client/local
          to avoid class loading problems for classes that are not needed on the server.
          To configure an alternative package filter for client-only classes, specify:
          -Derrai.client.local.class.pattern=.*/myproject/client/.* -->
          <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx2048m -XX:CompileThreshold=7000 -Derrai.jboss.home=${errai.jboss.home} -Derrai.dev.context=${errai.dev.context}</extraJvmArgs>
          <server>org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.gwt.EmbeddedWildFlyLauncher</server>
          <disableCastChecking>true</disableCastChecking>
          <runTarget>${errai.dev.context}/</runTarget>
          <soyc>false</soyc>
          <hostedWebapp>src/main/webapp</hostedWebapp>
          <strict>true</strict>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <filesets>
            <fileset>
              <directory>${basedir}</directory>
              <includes>
                <include>src/main/webapp/app/</include>
                <include>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/deploy/</include>
                <include>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/</include>
                <include>**/gwt-unitCache/**</include>
                <include>.errai/</include>
              </includes>
            </fileset>
          </filesets>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <!-- Unpack jboss-as from maven. Remove this if you wish to use your
      own jboss/wildfly instance. -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>unpack</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                  <artifactId>wildfly-dist</artifactId>
                  <version>${as.version}</version>
                  <type>zip</type>
                  <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>jboss7</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
              <packagingExcludes>**/javax/**/*.*,**/client/local/**/*.class</packagingExcludes>
              <outputFileNameMapping>@{artifactId}@-@{baseVersion}@@{dashClassifier?}@.@{extension}@</outputFileNameMapping>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
            <extensions>false</extensions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
          <artifactId>errai-jboss-as-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava-gwt</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
          <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
          <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
          <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
          <classifier>sources</classifier>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
          <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
          <classifier>sources</classifier>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
          <artifactId>errai-cdi-jboss</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
          <artifactId>errai-codegen-gwt</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
          <artifactId>errai-data-binding</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
          <artifactId>errai-javax-enterprise</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
          <artifactId>errai-jaxrs-client</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
          <artifactId>errai-jpa-client</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
          <artifactId>errai-navigation</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
          <artifactId>errai-tools</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
          <artifactId>errai-ui</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
          <artifactId>errai-html5</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
          <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.interceptor</groupId>
          <artifactId>jboss-interceptors-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
          <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>weld-servlet-core</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
          <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
          <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
          <artifactId>netty-codec-http</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>mobile</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
            <artifactId>cordova-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${errai.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>build</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>build-project</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>snapshots.jboss.org</id>
          <name>JBoss Snapshot Repository</name>
          <url>http://snapshots.jboss.org/maven2</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

### **App.gwt.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.5.0//EN"  
            "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.5.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">  


<module rename-to="app">  
  <inherits name="org.jboss.errai.enterprise.All" />  
  <inherits name="org.jboss.errai.ui.nav.Navigation"/>  
  <inherits name="org.jboss.errai.bus.ErraiBus"/>  
  <inherits name="org.jboss.errai.ioc.Container"/>  
  <set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE"/>  
  <!-- Uncomment the line below to enable all logging statements (default  
  level is "INFO"). -->  
  <!-- <set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="ALL"/> -->  
</module>
```

### **web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">  


  <welcome-file-list>  
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>  
  </welcome-file-list>  

  <servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>  
  </servlet-mapping>  

  <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>ErraiServlet</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.errai.bus.server.servlet.DefaultBlockingServlet</servlet-class>  
    <init-param>  
      <param-name>auto-discover-services</param-name>  
      <param-value>true</param-value>  
    </init-param>  


    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
  </servlet>  

  <servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>ErraiServlet</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>*.erraiBus</url-pattern>  
  </servlet-mapping>  

  <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>ErraiServlet</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.errai.bus.server.servlet.StandardAsyncServlet</servlet-class>  
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>  
  </servlet>  


</web-app>
```

### **LoginForm.java -> client side**

```
package org.jboss.errai.demo.client.local;  


import com.google.gwt.dom.client.FormElement;  
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;  
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;  
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;  
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite;  
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox;  
import javax.inject.Inject;  
import org.jboss.errai.common.client.api.Caller;  
import org.jboss.errai.common.client.api.RemoteCallback;  
import org.jboss.errai.demo.client.local.share.UserAccount;  
import org.jboss.errai.demo.client.local.share.LoginResponse;  
import org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.api.EntryPoint;  
import org.jboss.errai.ui.nav.client.local.DefaultPage;  
import org.jboss.errai.ui.nav.client.local.Page;  
import org.jboss.errai.ui.shared.api.annotations.Bound;  
import org.jboss.errai.ui.shared.api.annotations.DataField;  
import org.jboss.errai.ui.shared.api.annotations.EventHandler;  
import org.jboss.errai.ui.shared.api.annotations.Model;  
import org.jboss.errai.ui.shared.api.annotations.Templated;  
import org.jboss.errai.demo.client.local.share.LoginVerifyService;  


/** 
* 
* @author ondra 
*/  
@EntryPoint  
@Page(role = DefaultPage.class)  
@Templated("LoginForm.html#container")  
public class LoginForm extends Composite{  


  @Inject  
  @Model  
  private UserAccount loginRequest;  

  @Inject  
  @Bound  
  @DataField  
  private TextBox password;  


  @Inject  
  @Bound  
  @DataField  
  private TextBox username;  


  @Inject  
  @DataField  
  private Button login;  


  @Inject  
  private Caller<LoginVerifyService> loginVerify;  


  @EventHandler("login")  
  private void onLoginClick(ClickEvent ce){  
    this.login.setFocus(false);  
    this.loginVerify.call(new RemoteCallback<LoginResponse>() {  
      @Override  
      public void callback(LoginResponse response){  
        Window.alert(response.toString());  
      }  
    }).authentication(loginRequest);  
  }  


}
```

### **LoginVerifyService -> rpc interface**

```
package org.jboss.errai.demo.client.local.share;  


import org.jboss.errai.bus.server.annotations.Remote;  


/** 
* 
* @author ondra 
*/  


@Remote  
public interface LoginVerifyService{  
  public LoginResponse authentication(UserAccount recieveUserAccount);  
}  

package org.jboss.errai.demo.client.local.share;  


import org.jboss.errai.bus.server.annotations.Remote;  


/** 
* 
* @author ondra 
*/  


@Remote  
public interface LoginVerifyService{  
  public LoginResponse authentication(UserAccount recieveUserAccount);  
}
```

### **LoginVerifyImpl -> rpc service**

```
package org.jboss.errai.demo.server;  


import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;  
import org.jboss.errai.bus.server.annotations.Service;  
import org.jboss.errai.demo.client.local.share.UserAccount;  
import org.jboss.errai.demo.client.local.share.LoginResponse;  
import org.jboss.errai.demo.client.local.share.LoginVerifyService;  


/** 
* 
* @author ondra 
*/  
@ApplicationScoped  
@Service  
public class LoginVerifyImpl implements LoginVerifyService{  




  private DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();  


  @Override  
  public LoginResponse authentication(UserAccount recieveUserAccount){  
    System.err.println("JSEM V METODE");  
    VerifyResponse response = this.dataSource.getUserByName(recieveUserAccount.getUsername());  
    UserAccount foundAccount = response.getUserAccount();  


    if(response.getQueryStatus() == VerifyResponse.Status.ACCOUNT_FOUND){  
      if(recieveUserAccount.getPassword().equals(foundAccount.getPassword())){  
        return new LoginResponse(LoginResponse.Response.ALL_OK, "vitejte na webu");  
      }else{  
        return new LoginResponse(LoginResponse.Response.PASS_BAD, "spatne heslo");  
      }  
    }else{  
      return new LoginResponse(LoginResponse.Response.USER_BAD, "spatny uzivtelsky ucet");  
    }  
  }  


}
```

Comment: Hey. Did You sovle this issue. I have exacly same problem. Any help apreciated

Comment: yeah i solved like charm....I changed my work. I don't like Errai...I founded Angular2 is much better for fronted and you don't need bee friendly with JavaScript becouse it using TypeScript. It is frendly for Java developers

Comment: I've restart pc and now it works back again :-)

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error when running Super Dev Mode through my IDE (IntelliJ).  When I ran Super Dev Mode through the GWT Maven Plugin (`mvn gwt:run -Dgwt.noserver`), this error went away.

I'm not sure what is causing the problem.  My first thought is that there was a version difference, but both the IDE and Maven Plugin are using the same version of GWT (2.8.0-beta1).

Hope this helps!